# How should I test my "Serverless" (API Gateway/Lambda/ECS) applications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, automated-tests, serverless, aws-serverless

I am using AWS API Gateway with Lambda/ECS for compute and Cognito for users. But I find it really hard to test such applications. With AWS SAM Local I maybe able to test simple Lambda and API gateway functionality but if I use things like API Gateway authorizers I find it hard to test these end to end.

Looks like to test such applications, I need an entire new setup just for testing? I mean like a separate API Gateway with Lambda/ECS cluster/Cognito user pool just to enable testing? This seems very slow, and I think I will not be able to get things like a code coverage report anymore?

Comment: What kinds of tests are you trying to run?

Comment: @lloyd API tests? I guess it's integration. Also what do you recommend for unit test? Just trigger the lambda manually?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to AWS Lambda/ECS/Cognito so take this with a grain of salt.

1. **Unit Tests**: SAM Local or some other local docker hosting with a unit testing library ([mocha](https://mochajs.org/)) would be good for this because:

   - Speed. All your tests should execute quickly against a lambda function
   - Example : [wildrydes](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshops) with mocha
2. **Integration Tests**: Once you stage your changes, there's a bunch of options calling the API. I'd start off with [postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to run the API tests and you can chain them together or run them in command line if needed.
3. **End to End (E2E) tests**: If the API is your front end then there might not be any difference between E2E and API tests. UI, Voice, Chat front ends differ significantly as do the options so I'll suggest some options:

   - UI : Selenium (has the most support and options available to you including docker images: Selenium Hub or standalone)
   - Voice: Suggestions?
   - Text: Suggestions?
4. **Step functions** :

   - allows you to visualize each step
   - retries when there are errors
   - allows you to diagnose and debug problems
5. **X-Ray**: collects data about requests that your app serves, and provides tools you can use to view

As for code coverage, I'm not sure how you currently do code coverage. Something like this [npm run coverage](https://github.com/focusaurus/hexagonal-lambda), maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using cloudformation for deploying such an extensive stack and the following answer is based on that assumption.

Thus in addition to the @lloyd's answer, I would like to add that you can add custom resources within your cloudformation template for testing each individual lambdas or even api endpoints.

Also for lambda, you can use Deployment Preferences Hooks to test your serverless lambdas before and after moving your lambda to the new version.

https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/release/v1.8.0/docs/safe_lambda_deployments.rst